# Is it true that use "BufferedImage" will get performance for loading images in wicket?

Tags: performance, wicket, frontend, imagesource

As to diagnose the best performant way in **wicket** for loading images by using "bufferedDynamicImageResource" and  "static image resource path", I've tried the following sample:

using "BufferedImage"

```
    BufferedImage _img = ImageIO.read(file);

    BufferedDynamicImageResource bufferedDynamicImage = new BufferedDynamicImageResource();
    bufferedDynamicImage.setImage(_img);
    Image image1 = new Image("img_1", bufferedDynamicImage);
```

using static resource path

```
    Image image2=new Image("img_2","5683466325_5431b65113_z.jpg");
```

The response time for loading images using "static resource" is about 299ms while using "BufferedImage" is only 58ms in the first load. I've tested it on local and deploy my on Tomcat. SO besides the JVM memory consideration problems, do we better getting images from memory instead of loading them from local disk if the images request resource is small enough?

Regards

Vance